# What's the best way to describe someone you do not know

Tags: synonyms

I am currently writing a University report disucssing a project I worked on. The project consisted of 7 people, including myself. The other 6 team members were essentially strangers, although I had seen them before, and in some cases, had a very brief exchange of a few words.

In the report I am very keen to avoid the term *stranger*, as I do not think it works in the context of the report, but I need another term to describe them. This is my current sentence:

> In second year, I was placed in a team of six other students, of which
>   I had never interacted with.

I would like to reformat the sentence into something along the lines of:

> In second year, I was placed in a team of six *strangers*.

Any ideas a word that would be better suited?

Comment: A **[*acquaintance*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/acquaintance)**, perhaps? Someone that you have been introduced to, but don't know very well.

Comment: Is the lack of prior interaction something you want to highlight in the report? Why isn't it sufficient to end the first sentence at the word *students*?

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, the fact that I had little-to-no interaction with these people is notable for the rest of the report.

Comment: @Mick Although some of the members could be defined as an acquaintance, it does not apply to all of students

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Why doesn't the word *strangers* work in your report, and what nuance or connotation etc do you want the new word or phrase to carry?

Comment: You could say ".....six other students, who I knew only slightly."    This raises another question:  how well did the six know each other before you joined the group?

Comment: @Lawrence _Strangers_ implies that I was not familiar with them. in the sense that I didn't know of their existence, but I did. Where as acquaintance almost implies I knew them more than I did. I would like a term that describes that I knew of them, but had little-to-no interaction with them.

Comment: *I was placed in a team **with six new faces***. Or be more precise (albeit somewhat "quirky") with ***new-to-me faces***. Or just ***...with six unfamiliar faces*** or similar.

Comment: @ab2 it varied, I knew one of the students slightly, I had one or two interactions with two others and no interactions with the remainder.

Comment: In that case, it may be better to state it explicitly, as you have in your first version. You can say that you were placed in a team with six other students you've had very little (prior) interaction with.

Comment: ...a team of six unfamiliar/unaccustomed students...

Comment: A lot of great suggestions there, really like 'with six new faces'. Your idea would work, Lawrence, but I need to reduce my word count as much as possible. I think I will go with @mahmudkoya's suggestion.

Comment: Your question implies that being put in a group with six strangers had some sort of effect on your work.  Did the six all knew each other well, and you came to the group as an outsider, or were all seven of you strangers, near strangers or at most slight acquaintances?   Do you have a question beyond an English question --- one for the Academic or Workplace site?

Comment: @ab2 The group was compiled by a third party, and we all came together at the same time. Each team member was in the same boat, in the sense that we all didn't/barely knew each other. The question is limited in scope, I only wish to know an appropriate word, therefore I think it is appropriate for this forum.

Comment: Then perhaps the important thing is all of the group were strangers to each other, not that six of them were strangers to you.

Comment: @ab2 The report is regarding my personal experience, so I don't think it is of relevance

Comment: strangers is not the right word here. They are quite simply: people I did not know. There is no way around it. Placed ON a team, not in a team. /I was placed on a team with six people I did not know or I had not met previously or before. (It would be so useful if the symbol varies with could be reproduced in these forums).

Comment: Consider "six people I knew, at best, only in passing"

Comment: Simple: six students new to me.

Comment: Why would you not call them 'near strangers' perhaps with hyphen?

Comment: "new acquaintances"